# Netbeans Error: Could not find or load main class java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have encounter this error anyone got suggestion to solving this?
I have tried deleting the cache appdata but it does not work.

Error: Could not find or load main class
C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\kailu\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans right-click on your class -> properties -> Run. Then find "Main Class" click "Browse..." and select your existing main class.

Comment: I have tested this, and it still does not work :/

Comment: That's strange...

Comment: Try this!!!!!
You need to avoid writing special characters like the semicolons (";") in the MyProjectName and everything will be ok! Just Rename Project from windows browser and try again))))

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the cache folder

1. Go to C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\NetBeans\
2. Delete the Cache folder.
3. Rebuild and Run

If it does not work, try these steps:

1. Right-click on the project in the left toolbar.
2. properties.
3. Click on Run
4. Click the browse button on the right side.(select your main class)
5. Click ok

Comment: Hi i have tried your first option while trying to build, i have this error message "javac: file not found: C:\Users\User\OneDrive\??\NetBeansProjects\Testing\src\testing\Testing.java"

Comment: Try setting your java path to Environment variables: 
open computer properties- Advanced system settings- Environment Variables - find the system variables option -Click on the "path" variable - 
 _other variables here_ ; C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121;
Then click ok and restart your computer